# CSS submenu positioning

Tags: css, menu, navigation, drop-down-menu, position

is it possible to keep the position of the 2nd level billboard fixed to the top as opposed to moving down the page on hover?

### Code

#### HTML

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#">LINK LINK ></a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
                <ul>

                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#">LINK LINK ></a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>

                        <div><a href="#">LINK LINK ></a></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div><a href="#">LINK LINK ></a></div>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>asdasdasd</div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>asdasdasd</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>asdasdasd</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">STUFF</a>
        <ul>

            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">STUFF</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navblue"><a href="#">STUFF</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="STUFF">STUFF</a></li>

            <li><a href="STUFF">STUFF</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="navorange"><a href="STUFF">STUFF</a></li>
</ul>​
```

#### CSS

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:   12px;
    color:       #000000;
}

#nav, #nav ul {
    list-style-type:     none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    position:            relative;
    line-height:         30px;
    margin:              0;
    padding:             0;
}

#nav li > a {
    font-weight:      bold;
    display:          block;
    margin-top:       -1px;
    color:            #fff;
    text-decoration:  none;
    background-color: #008000;
    padding:          0 10px;
    width:            99px;
    border-bottom:    1px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#nav li > a:hover {
    background-color: #99CC00;
    color:            #000;
}

#nav li {
    float:        left;
    position:     relative;
    margin-right: 1px;
}

#nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    display:  none;
    width:    12em;
    top:      2.5em;
}

#nav li ul a {
    width:       160px;
    height:      auto;
    float:       left;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size:   12px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#nav ul ul {
    top: auto;
}

#nav ul ul {
    height:           299px;
    width:            652px;
    margin:           0;
    padding:          0;
    background-color: #999999;
}

#nav ul ul li {
    padding: 20px;
}

#nav li.navblue a {
    background-color: #3398CC;
}

#nav li.navorange a {
    background-color: #FF9A02;
    color:            #FEFF00;
}

#nav li ul ul {
    left:        14.9em;
    margin-left: -2px;
}

#nav li:hover ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul, #nav li:hover ul ul ul ul {
    display: none
}

#nav li:hover ul, #nav li li:hover ul, #nav li li li:hover ul, #nav li li li li:hover ul {
    display: block
}​
```

#### JavaScript/jQuery

```
window.addEvent('load', function () {
    function mainmenu() {
        $("#nav ul").css({display:"none"}); // Opera Fix
        $("#nav li").hover(function () {
            $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility:"visible", display:"none"}).show(0);
        }, function () {
            $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility:"hidden"});
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        mainmenu();
    });
})​
```

**[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pEdaE/)**

Comment: please add your code to www.jsfiddle.net so that we can see a live demo instead of using pastie

Comment: Please create a limited example testcase of the problem and paste the code here, in the body of your question. It would also help if you used http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your current css with this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
body {font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;color:#000000;}
#nav,#nav ul{list-style-type:none;list-style-position:outside;position:relative;line-height:30px;margin:0;padding:0;}
#nav li > a{font-weight:bold;display:block;margin-top:-1px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;background-color:#008000;padding:0 10px;width:99px;border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;}
#nav li > a:hover{background-color:#99CC00;color:#000;}
#nav li{float:left;margin-right:1px;}
#nav ul{position:absolute;display:none;width:12em;top:2.5em;}
#nav li ul a{width:160px;height:auto;float:left;line-height:30px;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;}
#nav ul ul{top:0;}
#nav ul ul {height:299px;width:652px;margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#999999;}
#nav ul ul li {padding:20px;}
#nav li.navblue a{background-color:#3398CC;}
#nav li.navorange a{background-color:#FF9A02;color:#FEFF00;}
#nav li ul ul{left:14.9em;margin-left:-2px;}
#nav li:hover ul ul,#nav li:hover ul ul ul,#nav li:hover ul ul ul ul{display:none}
#nav li:hover ul,#nav li li:hover ul,#nav li li li:hover ul,#nav li li li li:hover ul{display:block}
</style>
```

Changes: remove relative position from #nav li and position #nav ul ul top:0

Comment: thanks! i was about to take a longer route creating classes and playing with positioning.

Comment: using this method where could i break the inheritance of the links within the billboard? they're using the 160 width thats on the dropdown

Comment: Be aware that if you use the above method that you may run into interface issues with long lists. You will not be able to navigate to the "2nd level billboard" When you hover over a list item that is below the bottom of the "billboard". You will lose the hover on the parent list item and the "billboard" will disappear. See http://jsfiddle.net/pEdaE/1/ as an example of what I mean.

Comment: thats fine. i dont plan on making it any longer than 8 items.